# $C(X)$-Fredholm operators and Atiyah-Jänich theorem

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, c-star-algebras, fredholm-operators, hilbert-modules

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff topological space and consider the Hilbert space $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$. As shown [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/239978/operators-on-hilbert-c-module-and-families-of-fredholm-operators?noredirect=1&lq=1), any $T\in C(X,\ell^2(\mathbb N))$ induces a $C(X)$-Fredholm operator
$$
\begin{array}{rccc}
\widehat{T}: &\mathscr H_{C(X)}& \rightarrow &\mathscr H_{C(X)} \\
& \xi & \mapsto &  \underbrace{\big(x \mapsto T_x\xi(x)\big)}_{T_{(\,\cdot\,)}\xi{(\,\cdot\,)}}
\end{array}
$$
in the standard Hilbert $C(X)$-module $\mathscr H_{C(X)}$. Following [Exel's approach](http://mtm.ufsc.br/%7Eexel/papers/morita.pdf), I'm trying to see a connection between the Atiyah-Jänich theorem and its ``non-commutative'' counterpart, Corollary 3.17. One can think $F(A)$ to the be set of classes of $A$-Fredholm operators, where each class has all operators with the same index.

Can this construction $\widehat{(\,\cdot\,)}: C(X,\ell^2(\mathbb N)) \longrightarrow \mathscr F(\mathscr H_{C(X)})$ induce a map such that the following commutes?

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
    {[X,\mathcal F(\ell^2(\mathbb N))]}  & \longrightarrow & F(C(X)) \\
    \text{ind}\downarrow \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,& & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\downarrow \text{ind}\\
    K^0(X) & \longrightarrow & K_0(C(X))                      
\end{array}
$$
I'm asking this because it doesn't seems too trivial to just calculate the index with bare hands. I was trying to pair up the index family approach $[\ker P_n\circ T]_0$ with $rank(\ker \widehat T)$, where $\ker P_n\circ T = \bigcup_{x\in X} \ker P_n\circ T_x$ and $\ker \widehat T = \bigcup_{x\in X} \ker T_x ev_x$.